# JSONP not working with .NET webservice and return html

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-ajax, jsonp

I have created simple webservice for return string data. Here is the code in default.aspx page

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void login(string name)
{

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    sb.Append("Callbabk(");
    //sb.Append(js.Serialize(name));
    sb.Append("{\"response\":\"testdata\"}");
    sb.Append(");");

    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ClearHeaders();
    Context.Response.ClearContent();
    Context.Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
    Context.Response.Expires = -1;
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset = utf - 8";
    Context.Response.Charset = "utf=8";
    Context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    Context.Response.Flush();
    Context.Response.Close();
    Context.Response.End();        
}
```

Also please see the jquery ajax function that i have created for accessing above remote webservice.

```
              function checkfun(){

                $.ajax({                
                    //crossDomain: true,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://remoteIPaddress/Default.aspx/login",
                    data: { name: "datatest" },                        
                    dataType: "jsonp",  
                    jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert('test:'+response);                            
                    }
                });

             }
             function OnSuccess(response) {
               alert(response.d);
             }
```

When i see the ajax call in Google Chrome Network, it shows me status 200 OK but in response it shows me html and ajax error function is raised. Also in console shows me error 'Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.'. So please please let me know why i am not getting response and getting such error.

Answer (score 0):

For Cross Domain JSONP, the quickest is to use handler

**Handler.ashx**

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

        var name = context.Request.QueryString["name"];
        var callback = context.Request.QueryString["callback"];

        var data = new { response = "name is " + name  };
        var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        context.Response.Write( callback + "("+ js.Serialize(data) + ")" );
        context.Response.End();        
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

and Call from **JS**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Handler.ashx",
    data: { name: "test" },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (json) {
        alert(json.response);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert('error:' + response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your idea but i need josnp and my webservice is on remote location so the above code get me 403 forbidden error. So i need to browse webservice by following url.    (http://remoteIPaddress/Default.aspx/login)

Comment: Is there any way to implement jsonp in Default.aspx page ?